# date_popup + theme = infinite loop

Tags: 7, forms, theming, datetime

I'm trying to create a templated form including date_popup field in a custom module. There is a very basic example : mkl_variousTest.module ( dependency : date_popup from date API )

```
<?php

//mkl_variousTest.module

/**
 * Implementation of hook_menu()
 * @return array
 */
function mkl_variousTest_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['testFormTemplate'] = array(
    'title' => t('Test form template'),
    'page callback' => 'mkl_variousTest_form_page',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );

  return $items;
}

/**
 * Implementation of hook_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path)
 * @param array $existing
 * @param string $type
 * @param string $theme
 * @param string $path
 * @return array
 */
function mkl_variousTest_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $themes = array();

  $themes['formPage'] = array(
    'template' => 'mkl_variousTest_formPage',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'mkl_variousTest') . '/templates',
    'variables' => array(
      'form' => drupal_get_form('mkl_variousTest_form'),
    ),
  );

  return $themes;
}

/**
 * Implementation of hook_form($form, &$formState)
 * @param node $node
 * @param array $formState
 * @return array
 */
function mkl_variousTest_form($node, &$formState) {
  $form = array();

  $form['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Nom'),
    '#lenght' => 60,
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );

  $form['date'] = array(
    '#type' => 'date_popup',
    '#title' => t('date'),
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('OK'),
  );

  return $form;
}

function mkl_variousTest_form_page() {
  return theme('formPage');
}

?>
```

Using this way, drupal run in an infinite loop and return this error :

> Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached,
>   aborting!

There is a printScreen :
[image: error printscreen]

Next, the same function calls between #19 to #37 are repeated until drupal stop the loop.
This append as soon as I have a date_popup field in my form.

So how can I fix it ?

PS : This is my template file mkl_variousTest_formPage.tpl.php :

```
<p>before</p>

<?php print drupal_render_children($form); ?>

<p>after</p>
```

Comment: Has it started looping infinitely when you added the `date_popup` field? Have you tried removing it? Are you sure it's got to do with the date_popup? What's in your `mkl-variousTest-formPage.tpl.php` template file?

Comment: hello Beebee, yes it is starting looping infinitely when I had the date_popup field. yes I have tried to remove it and it works fine. yes I'm sure the problem is about the date_popup field. I will update my post to add the template file now, but it is a very basic one too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stab in the dark, but I think your problem is probably stemming from the fact that you're building the form from within a theme function, which in turn calls another theme function, then so on and so forth. Logically theming should be after you've built the form.

Replace `drupal_get_form('mkl_variousTest_form')` in `hook_theme()` to `NULL` and in your page callback add the following code.

```
$form = drupal_get_form('mkl_variousTest_form');
return theme('formPage', array('form' => $form));
```